# Laravel missing argument 2

Tags: laravel-4

> Missing argument 2 for
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute(), called in
>   /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 2335 and defined

The above I get trying to upload a CSV file.

Controller:

```
 public function postUpload ()
{
    if ( Input::hasFile('file') )
    {
        DB::transaction(function()
        {
            // Clear out what we have written
            DB::table('wc_program')->delete();

            $csv = new CsvFile(Input::file('file')->getRealPath());

            // Get the csv headers and move to the next line (the start of actual data)
            $columns = $csv->getHeader();
            $csv->next();

            // Loop through the rows creating / saving a record for each
            while( $csv->valid() )
            {
                $row = $csv->current();
                $pc = new Programmes();

                for( $i=0; $i<count($columns); $i++ )
                {
                    $pc->$columns[$i] = $row[$i];
                }

                $pc->save();
                $csv->next();
            }
        });

    return Redirect::to('admin/programmes')->with('flash_success', 'Upload completed &amp; new data inserted.');
    }
```

Then I have a model thats just really basic and nothing major like so:

```
 class Programmes extends Eloquent {

 protected $guarded = array('id');
//public static $rules = array();

 protected $table = 'wc_program_1';

 public $timestamps = false;
 }
```

And routes setup like:

```
Route::get('admin/programmes/excelUpload','ProgrammesController@excelUpload');
Route::post('admin/programmes/doUpload', ['as' => 'admin.programmes.doUpload', 'uses' => 'ProgrammesController@postUpload']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute()` expects two arguments, key and its value. It seems that your value is missing while being assigned to the column.

I suggest you to debug your code near at

```
$pc->$columns[$i] = $row[$i];
```

Please update your question if you find something helpful :)